# Does Perl 6 nativecast() to an object with repr('CPointer') DESTROY when GC'ed?

Tags: casting, raku, nativecall

Reading [Basic use of Pointers](https://docs.perl6.org/language/nativecall#Basic_use_of_Pointers) indicates that when a `NativeCall` C function returns pointer to an object with a class with `repr('CPointer')`, it will call `submethod DESTROY` where I can put my function to free the C memory.  (This is fantastic and an amazing capability, btw.)

What if I get back a generic `Pointer`, but later decide to `nativecast()` it to the class?  Will that also correctly `DESTROY()` it when garbage collected?  I think (and hope) it will, but haven't been able to prove that to myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suspect it will, given the behaviour of the following test case:

```
use NativeCall;

my $done = False;

class Foo is repr<CPointer> {
    method id { nativecast(Pointer[int32], self).deref }

    # only log destrution of first object
    submethod DESTROY {
        if !$done {
            $done = True;
            say "first Foo with id {self.id} has died";
        }
    }
}

# avoid premature collection of buffers
my @keep-alive;

# allocate a bunch of buffers and cast them to Foo
# keep going until the garbage collector gets triggered
my $ = nativecast(Foo, @keep-alive.push(buf32.new($++)).tail)
    while !$done;
```

The destructor will be called when a `Foo` gets reclaimed, even if said `Foo` was created via a `nativecast`. If you want, you may add an explicit conversion to `Pointer` inbetween, but that shouldn't and doesn't make any difference.